# Street fighter 4 on laptop

Tags: pc, street-fighter-iv

I just get a street fighter 4 pc version and installed on laptop machine. however, it is really slow. My laptop is 2 dual-core CPU and 3G mem, and with integrated video card... is there any workaround?

Comment: Do you have the latest video drivers? Is your laptop plugged in (some laptops reduce the cpu speed when unplugged to extend battery life)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is your integrated video card.  Most likely its not up to the task of rendering SF4.  I would suggest try turning down every setting in the video options, but that may not be enough.

Answer (score 2):

Depends. You can use a program like 3DAnalyze to force your CPU to handle certain tasks that the program wants the GPU to do, but this is very suboptimal.

You'll want to make sure all your drivers are updated before trying anything, too.

Really, though, your best bet is just closing all possible programs and services (i.e. explorer.exe) while playing and hoping for the best. Otherwise, you'll just need to get a new laptop/PC, or try and hunt down an external graphics card.